# Создание комнаты в чате с использованием FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Ребят,такой вопрос. Имеется приложение чат с использованием firebase database. Реализована переписка между юзерами,но при запуске приложения получается что существует всего одна комната. 
Вопрос  в следующем : есть ли возможность создать некие комнаты,при тапе на которых собственно пользователь в нее попадает?

Проблема в том,что при создании модели данных для firebase,необходимо указать точное название переменной,которое будет соответствовать определенному подкадалогу(т.е. в моем случае название комнаты),но оно мне не известно зарание. 
Буду благодарен любым наводкам!

Comment: 1. Создайте объект со списком комнат в бд.
2. Получите на клиенте список комнат.

Comment: т.е. в модели вместо String name, создать List<String> name, я правильно вас понял? и как получить список комнат на клиенте?прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток. Попробуйте сделать так
В официальной документации есть раздел ["Structure data"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data), там показывается, как необходимо формировать структуру БД в большинстве случаев. Для вас подойдет такой:

```
{
// Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
// stored under the chats's unique ID
"chats": {
  "one": {
    "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
    "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
    "timestamp": 1459361875666
  },
  "two": { ... },
  "three": { ... }
},

// Conversation members are easily accessible
// and stored by chat conversation ID
"members": {
// we'll talk about indices like this below
"one": {
  "ghopper": true,
  "alovelace": true,
  "eclarke": true
},
"two": { ... },
"three": { ... }
},

// Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
// but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
// conversation ID
"messages": {
"one": {
  "m1": {
    "name": "eclarke",
    "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
    "timestamp": 1459361875337
  },
  "m2": { ... },
  "m3": { ... }
},
"two": { ... },
"three": { ... }
}
}
```

Как это все будет работать: у вас есть список  пользователей, все они парсятся с БД, потом юзер выбирает одного из них и отправляет ему первое сообщение. Создается новый чат с уникальным id ("one", "two" etc.., как в коде выше).(Либо можно сначала создавать комнату с id, в потом приглашать туда пользователей, которые будут записываться в "members")

Чат заносится в различные ветки ("members", "messages", etc..), которые отвечают за данные в чате. Благодаря timestamp, сообщения автоматически будут сортироваться по новизне.

Можно сделать список публичных комнат (чатов)- просто парсить данные с ветки "chats'